# Boot Device Not Found in Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ubuntu-gnome

I think I accidentally deleted some partition in GNOME Disks software. Now when I restarted the PC, it won't boot up. It says boot device not found. I run dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First time installing (erasing Windows) from usb, did everything just so, Boot Device Not Found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818843/first-time-installing-erasing-windows-from-usb-did-everything-just-so-boot-d)